# MySQL PDO Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

The below code is returning the error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`first_name`, `last_name`, `username`) VALUES ('Joseph', 'NotRandom', 'nolonger' at line 1

```
try {
   $sql = "UPDATE `ekar_users` SET (`first_name`, `last_name`, `username`) VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :username) WHERE id= $user_id";
   $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
   $query->execute( array ( ":first_name" => $_POST['fname'], ":last_name" => $_POST['lname'], ":username" => $_POST['username'] ) );
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
   // handle error 
   echo $e->getmessage();
   exit();
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Update is different from insert, please check documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html

Comment: You should state what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` syntax is wrong. Additionally, you didn't parameterize `$user_id` so I added that for you

```
UPDATE `ekar_users` SET 
    `first_name` = :first_name, 
    `last_name` = :last_name, 
    `username`= :username
WHERE id= :user_id
```